# How can I open a link in a terminal window with a double-click action?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I would like to open `http` links with a double click from the default terminal window in Ubuntu Unity. The following animation demonstrates the question:

[image: GIF animation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also hold the `Ctrl` key and click the link - is the same as right click and select `Open Link`

Comment: That is a great answer, FredFoo.  Great find!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, unless you want to go to the source code, edit it and recompile.

As you no doubt already saw, however, you can right-click the link and click `Open Link`, which will open it in your default browser

Comment: Thank you! Would you recommend me to file a feature request bug report?

Comment: You certainly could do.  It's worth the try just to see if the community run with it.

Comment: And, BTW, I tried a bunch of other terminals while I was at it, and I haven't found any where it works or is even in the preferences.